# JWT expired issue in spring boot project

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

i am getting this error                                                                    io.jsonwebtoken.ExpiredJwtException: JWT expired at 2023-09-16T01:00:37Z. Current time: 2023-09-21T18:16:53Z, a difference of 494176433 milliseconds.  Allowed clock skew: 0 milliseconds. How to solve this issue

Comment: Use a new token?

Answer (score 0):

Check if time on your PC is set correctly. Also provide the configuration you are using so we can see. I think I could help if you sent the config.